# Capybara does not follow 308 redirect

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

I am using Cucumber and Capybara to perform some acceptance tests.

To my understanding, [capybara should follow redirects](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#clicking-links-and-buttons), and as I see, it does... usually.

Recently we have made some changes in the infrastructure. This change creates a 308 redirect code, instead of the previously generated 301. With this 308 code, it seems like capybara no longer follows it.

When running my test, I can clearly see that it didn't:

```
expected to find text "Welcome" in "308 Permanent Redirect nginx/1.13.8" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

I should mention that in the past (with the 301 redirect) the exact same test worked.

Is this a capybara bug? If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't `capybara` not following 308s, it's that the driver you're using with `capybara` isn't following 308s.  That driver is `capybara-webkit` and depending on what version of QtWebkit you built it against is roughly equivalent to a 5-9 year old browser which doesn't really support a lot of things modern browsers do. You're going to have a lot fewer issues around browser support if you swap to using selenium with headless chrome as your driver for at least some of your tests (those that require newer browser features)

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I thought about that same thing and opened an issue on capybara webkit. But why is it such an old browser? It is still a maintained gem... and don't get me started on selenium - I tried switching and it caused me much more problems than any other driver - wasted way too many hours on issues it created for me. Not going near it again. https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/1067

Comment: @DannyB It's that development on QtWebkit stopped a number of years ago.  There has been recent work to revive it but capybara-webkit hasn't been updated to use the latest beta versions.  As for selenium, it should just be a matter of adding `selenium-webdriver` to your Gemfile,  installing `chromedriver` and specifying `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless` (if you're running your tests locally) - not sure why you would have so many issues (unless you've been writing a lot of tests that access driver specific methods `page.driver.xxx`)